# How to manual update a private WordPress plugin from free to pro version

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have a wordpress plugin in my wordpress repo. It's a free version. There are some features that are only available in the pro version of the wordpress plugin. I put a download link from where users need to buy the **Pro version**.

Now I want such a way that when the user uploads the pro version it will update the codes of the free version and add the new features/functionality to the free version. It's a manual upload. How to achieve this with code/plugin development? give an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have one plugin for the free version and another plugin for the pro version that extends the functionality of the free one via custom- or existing WordPress hooks (actions/filters).